# Share your ssh tunnel on your local network (ubuntu)

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I want to make a connection to a remote server through a local server and share the connection on my local network using an OpenVPN or an ssh tunnel.

[image]
The reason I cannot directly connect to the remote server (for example using OpenVPN on the router) is that I don't want all the traffic to go through the remote server (the internet would be faster it doesn't).

Now I want to give users the possibility to use the services that the remote server offers (like filesharing). 
I know when I do this using OpenVPN, I can contact all ports, but I don't want all the traffic to go over that line.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you can simply open the Port(s) (Port Forwarding) in the router and connect FROM remote to your Server already.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to route all of your traffic over SSH, or are you trying to set up a Local Socks Proxy that specific applications can use to tunnel traffic through the machine?  There are so many solutions.  What is your actual goal? How many ports?  Browser and SSH? or more than that?

Comment: Hey @EODCraftStaff the reason I don't go to open a port on the router is that some of the traffic is unencrypted. For example, a samba share that goes through port 139.  To come back at the question of I want to route all traffic over ssh. No, I don't want to. Only a few ports. Because else an OpenVPN connection (using, for example, OpenWrt) would be awesome. The problem is that I can't figure out how I can share the ports trough the local server. Using OpenVPN to connect to the server could also be the second option. But it does not tackle sharing those ports (/portforwarding)

Comment: Please take a step back, think about what you want to accomplish exactly and then [edit] your question so it's clear what you're trying to accomplish instead of leaving golden nuggets of information strewn around the comments.  **;-)**